# rosjava_jni or rosjava

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all,

Just wonder what the status of ROSJAVA (pure Java implementation) is now. I am at the stage of choosing between RORJAVA and ROSJAVA_JNI. Is ROSJAVA reliable and mature enough for use, at least for basic functions, e.g. service server/client? I know ROSJAVA_JNI is also partial implementation, but it seems to have been used by some libraries for quite a while. It looks ok for my task.
I do not need to run it on Android or similar, only on my PC. Is there any advantage of using pure java implementation then?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11685/rosjava_jni-or-rosjava/) by [Ze JI](https://answers.ros.org/users/1235/ze-ji/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2011-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosjava_jni is no longer being developed, so you are best off using rosjava.  rosjava is regularly used to develop applications on Android, so, from a technology point of view, it is ready to use, though it is still in 'alpha' state and may have some API and tooling changes as it matures.

rosjava_jni and rosjava have different APIs, so you are better off in the long run using rosjava.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Last summer, I was working with both projects. In my opinion current rosjava is more stable and it has more features that jni version. Anyway, exist it is necessary to evolve the project in 2012.

---

Originally posted by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) with karma: 274 on 2012-01-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1